# django many to one relationships

Tags: django, django-models

In the django document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/, there are two tables, Report and Article,

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['headline']
```

My question, if you have a list of Reports, how would you get their articles? I've tried

```
articles = []
for report in reports:
    article = Article.objects.filter(report = report)
    articles.append(article )
```

but this does not give me all my data.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="articles")
```

Then you can just do `reporter.articles.all()`

Note: if your `ForeignKey` field doesn't have a `related_name` attribute, you can get the reverse relatioship by calling `<model_name>_set`. For example: `reporter.article_set.all()`

Comment: YES!! It worked!!!! Thank you so much!!!!